# How to make an unique div id?

Tags: javascript

here is my html markup... the problem is the javascript looping doesnt work... i did some kind of mistakes.. i dont know why... i want to loop $('#opt_art').mouseover etc... and every loop makes the script like this first loop $('#opt_art1).mouseover, second loop $('#opt_art2).mouseover, etc

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var i = 0;
            do{
                var num = i;
                $('#opt_art'+num).mouseover(function(){
                    $('.opsi'+num).show();
                });
                $('#opt_art'+num).mouseout(function(){
                    $('.opsi'+num).fadeOut(2000);
                });
                i++;    
            }
            while(i<=2);
        });
    </script>
    <?php
        for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){
    ?>
        <div id="art_category"><p>News</p></div><!-- end of category -->
        <div id="art_title"><p>Sherlock Holmes 2</p></div><!-- end of art_title -->
        <div id="rounded_artikel">
            <li><img src="images/42897.jpg" width="110" height="110" class="art_image"/></li>
            <ul><li><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec bibendum bibendum magna at egestas. Sed commodo gravida arcu id accumsan. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque vulputate, velit vitae pellentesque condimentum, lectus mi tempor nisl, sed sagittis est massa eu justo. Cras sed quam sed mauris elementum consectetur. Nunc vitae tortor diam, in hendrerit risus. Nulla et diam non libero vehicula blandit. Etiam facilisis, risus mattis venenatis iaculis, risus dolor lobortis sapien, a malesuada magna nibh nec tellus. Integer viverra, sapien quis pellentesque lobortis, tellus erat mattis nulla, vitae laoreet erat dolor sed ante.</p></ul></li>
        </div><!-- end of rounded_artikel -->
        <div id="art_info">
            <img src="images/communication-icon.png" width="23" height="23" class="comment"/><li class="total_komentar"><a href="#">123</a> Komentar</li>
            <img src="images/40395696544694793.png" width="23" height="21" class="art_date_icon"/><li class="art_date">19-06-2012</li>
            <img src="images/1903484911.png" width="23" height="21" class="author_icon"/><li class="author">straw_hat</li>
            <div id="opt_art<?=$i;?>">Option<?php echo $i; ?></div>
            <div class="opsi<?=$i;?>"><center><a href="#">Readmore</a> | <a href="#">Comment</a></center></div>
        </div><!-- end of art_info -->
    <?php } ?>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: shouldn't you increase `i`?

Comment: What does not work? Does it only work for class `.opsi5`?

Answer (score 3):

You forget to increment `i` variable:

```
   ...
   });
   i++;
}
while(i<=5);
```

Comment: upss sorry... i totally forgot to type it in this question :) my bad... i already type i++;.. but it doesnt work either

Comment: sorry i cant... i dont have 100 reputation... so i cant submitted it

Answer (score 2):

*Why* it isn't working for you has [already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10536485/444991) [been](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10536482/444991) answered, however I'd like to offer a *better* alternative to what you're doing.

Binding an event handler to multiple elements *smells*. You're looping over the matched set and adding an event handler *for each element*.

Instead you should attach the handler to *one* element and take advantage of [event bubbling](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110883/how-does-event-bubbling-generally-work-and-is-it-synonym-to-event-propagation). This can be done using the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method and the optional selector.

```
$(document).on('mouseover  mouseout', '[id^="opt_"]', function (e) {
    var el = $('.opsi'  + this.id.slice('opt_'.length));

    if (e.type === "mouseover") {
        el.show();
    } else {
        el.fadeOut(2000);
    }
});
```

The above code listens for a `mouseover` or `mouseout` event to fire, and checks whether it happened on an element whose ID [begins with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `opt_`, if it does it executes the event handler.

For more information you could read the full documentation for [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)

Comment: How does it work? Doesnt it select classes like `.opsiopt_art1`?

Comment: when the #opt_art1 is over cursor... the .opsi showed up... it an article feature.. i want to make when the cursor over the menu #opt_art, the second menu name .opsi show up with menu readmore and comment..

Comment: @Amberlamps: The [attribute begins with selector (`^=`)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) is only targeting elements whose ID begins with `opt_`

Comment: @Matt: I see, but the elements´s id is still `opt_[number]`, therefore `this.id` is refering to the whole string not just the number, isn´t it?

Comment: @Amberlamps: Aha, now I see ;). Indeed it does... thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Matt: No problem! I like the approach!

Answer (score 0):

You are not incermenting `i` also you can just use `i` variable instead of second var `num`. Try this.

```
var i = 1;
do{
   $('#opt_art'+i).mouseover(function(){
    $('.opsi'+i).show();
   });  
   $('#opt_art'+i).mouseout(function(){
        $('.opsi'+i).fadeOut(2000);
   });
}
while(i++<=5);
```